# Nesting async functions with .then()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, callback, antd

Re-visiting web dev after some time away, and I want to chain together asynchronous functions without the old callback hell paradigm

So I have a login component in my React app, with the onFinish function (using AntD):

```
onFinish(values) {
    const req = {
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password
    }
    userService.getUser(req)
      .then((res) => console.log('complete', res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
```

And I have a service layer built to connect with my API:

```
//In userService.js
async function getUser(req) {
  console.log(req);
  axios
    .get("/api/user", {params: {email: req.email, password: req.password}
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data) {
        console.log('we have data');
        return res.data;
      } else {
        console.log('no data');
        return res.data;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

I'd like for both console logs in the `userService.getUser(req)` to finish before we move onto the `.then()` in the `onFinish()` function. When I test an invalid login, my console output is

```
Object { email: "XX@XX.com", password: "XX" } user.service.js:27
complete undefined login.component.js:22
no data user.service.js:36
```

Any guidance on what I'm missing? Would also love to understand where I'd put a final, third function `saveJWTToken(user)`, than runs even after `userService.getUser(req)` is complete but needs to have its output passed back up to `onFinish()`

Comment: Does returning the promise in onFinish help? `return userService.getUser(req)....`

Comment: also `return axios.get("/api/user"`

Comment: Fantastic folks thanks. Had the first ```return userService.getUser(req)```, at one point but never the second. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things, tht you need to know,

First, you need to return the request from from getUser function
Secondly, if you are catching the error else where, you don't need to catch in the user request

Also since promises are chainable, you can call the `saveJWTToken(user)` in .then of getUser

```
//In userService.js
function getUser(req) {
  return axios
    .get("/api/user", {params: {email: req.email, password: req.password}
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data) {
        console.log('we have data');
        return res.data;
      } else {
        console.log('no data');
        return res.data;
      }
    }).then(() => {
        const token = saveJWTToken(user);
        return {user, token}
    })
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks! Just one follow-up, if we have two ```.then()``` calls in ```getUser()``` with two separate return functions, which value gets returned to the initial ```onFinish()```?

Comment: @AlexChumbley The return value of each .then call gets returned to the next one